# Webpack 5 compile scss in separated css files

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5

I'm trying to compile scss files in separated css files. For example, in my scss folder I have `main.scss`, `backend.scss`, `ajax.scss`, etc.
I want to keep `main.css`, `backend.css`, `ajax.css` ... files in my dist folder.
Is it possible to watch entire scss folder?

How can I do that? I have already tried MiniCssExtractPlugin and other modules, without success.
Thank you for your help.